# $viewContentLoaded gets triggered multiple times in Angular ngRoute application

Tags: angularjs, dom-events, ngroute

I have a pretty straight forward set up two tabs, home and admin:

```
  $routeProvider
             // route for the home page
             .when('/home', {
             templateUrl : 'views/home.html',
             controller  : 'myCtrl',
             controllerAs: 'vm',
             resolve:{
                 loadDropDowns:function(DataSvc,$rootScope){
                    
                        return DataSvc.GetDropDowns();
                    
                 }
             }
         })
         // route for admin page
         .when('/admin',{
             templateUrl : 'admin/templates/admin.html'             
         })
```

and in the controller, I have a listener for `$viewContentLoaded` event
like so:

```
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event){
        console.log(" viewContentLoaded fired ");
      });
```

And every time I click on the home tab, the event handler firings double  so first time its 2 , than 4 , than 8 and so on...

I have another event broadcasted when the drop downs are loaded, and for one brodcasted event, I get multiple firings of the handler as well.

```
 $rootScope.$broadcast('dropDownsSet');
```

and in the same controller :

```
    $rootScope.$on('dropDownsSet', function(event, mass) {}
```

gets executed multiple times as well.. ( same as above, every time doubling the number of times the event handler firing)

I'm at my wits end, what could be the cause for this madness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move event binding code

```
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event){
  console.log(" viewContentLoaded fired ");
});
```

from `myCtrl` controller to some main application (parent) controller. What happens now is that every time you navigate to Home tab, `myCtrl` gets instantiated, thus registering one more event listener on the `$rootScope`.

Comment: this is a great suggestion. Thank you !! This is the parent controller. is there a way to clear all other events when registering a new one?

Comment: You could remove event handlers (see Ved's answer) but I think it's better to design your controllers and events so that it's not needed.

Comment: Thanks for your help , I've been trying to figure this out for days now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$rootScope.$on('dropDownsSet', function(event, mass) {}
```

`$rootScope` listener events are not destroyed aromatically. You need to destroy it using $destroy. it is better to use `$scope.$on` as listener on $scope are destroyed automatically.

```
$scope.$on('dropDownsSet', function(event, mass) {}
```

Or,

```
  var customeEventListener = $rootScope.$on('dropDownsSet', function(event, mass) {

    }

 $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        customeEventListener();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Ved, this is superhelpful